# Defining Reads[X] where X has Private Constructor

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Given a `Person` class with a 'smart constructor', i.e. only "valid" values in `Person#build` will construct a `Person`:

```
case class Person private(age: Int)

object Person {
  def build(age: Int): Option[Person] = 
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 125) Some(Person(age)) else None     
}
```

I created a `Reads[Person]` by putting it into the `Person`'s companion object:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val reads: Reads[Person] = 
   (__ \ 'age).read[Int].map(a => 
    Person.build(a).getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("invalid age")            
   )
```

Is there a better way? I'd prefer to avoid the exception if it's possible.

Comment: Why don't you use case class Person(age: Int) { require(age >= 0 && age <= 125, "invalid age") } ?

Comment: To avoid exceptions, i.e. use Monads over exceptions

Comment: What about defining the Reads in the companion object?

Comment: @pedrofurla - I thought that I made it clear that I had added the `Reads[Person]` to the companion object. And, there's a related discussion -https://twitter.com/Gentmen/status/748610458819530752

Comment: Completely missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to drop the play functional style you could leverage the `JsResult` monad:

```
new Format[Person] {
  override def writes(o: Person): JsValue = ???

  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Person] = {
    try{
      json.as[JsObject].value.get("age")
        .flatMap(age => Person.build(age.as[Int])).map(JsSuccess(_))
        .getOrElse(JsError("wrong age"))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        JsError("wrong age")
    }
  }
}

val person = Json.toJson(Person.build(30))

val parsed: \/[String, Person] =  person.validate[Person].map(\/-(_)).getOrElse(-\/("some bad request"))
```

So it's a bit more complex than I suggested in my comment but basically you can wrap the parsing into a method which converts a `JsSuccess` to a right and a `JsError` to a left, the `try/catch` I use to catch the case where the sent json is not an object but only a value or in case the age field is not an integer.